# Why are Unique Factorization Domains (UFD's) geometrically significant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, intuition, unique-factorization-domains

We know that for $A$ a UFD, it's class group is trivial. More generally, for a factorial (stalks are UFD's) scheme $X$ (that is also noetherian and normal), we have an isomorphism between it's Picard group and it's Class group.

Should I expect this result to make sense before proving it? Is there a geometric significance to UFD's? I do not know of any other significant theorem that needs as its assumptions factoriality. Why is it suddenly important here and what does it have to do with divisors/line bundles?

Comment: If $X$ is an integral normal scheme, it is always true that the Picard group is isomorphic to the group of *Cartier* divisors modulo linear equivalence.  

Cartier divisors are by definition those that can be locally defined by a single equation and if $X$ is locally UFD then it is easy to see that every divisor is a Cartier divisor.

Comment: Does locally UFD mean small open sets are UFD? I don't think this is the same as stalks being UFD?

Comment: No, locally UFD means that the stalks are UFD. You're right that this does not imply that the affine open sets are UFD.

Comment: Thanks, this is off topic but do you know an easy counter example?

Comment: Any Dedekind domain is locally a UFD, but globally a UFD means it is a pid. Think of say, the co-ordinate ring of an affine open subset of an elliptic curve over complex numbers. No affine open set is a UFD, though locally it is.

Comment: Well said, @Mohan!